# Sqlite select distinct with Where

Tags: android, sqlite, select

I'm searching through my sqlite database from my android app using the following:

The rows of the database are:
`ID - KEY_NUMBER - TYPE`

`Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT "+KEY_NUMBER+" from "+TABLE + " DESC", null);`

But I only want to pull distinct values out of the `KEY_NUMBER` column if the

`TYPE column!=another value`

How would I do this? I tried inserting a `Where` statement but it didn't work.

The TYPE column could be one of 3 values: `"type1","type2","type3"`
I only want the number if the `TYPE!="type1"` or in order terms if the `TYPE=="type2" || "type3"`

Comment: What does the `TYPE` column need to be different from?

Comment: I just edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, then the `WHERE` clause should look like this:

```
WHERE TYPE IN ('type2', 'type3')
```

And in the end, the whole line should look like this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT " + KEY_NUMBER + " from " + TABLE + " WHERE TYPE IN ('type2', 'type3') ORDER BY KEY_NUMBER DESC", null);
```

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't work. `Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT "+KEY_NUMBER+" from "+TABLE + " WHERE " +
TYPE + " IN ('type2', 'type3') " + " DESC", null);`

Comment: Maybe you should introduce your ordering clause with "order by". See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to remove the `DESC` keyword, and add `where type != '<your_value>'`. Your query should be:

`db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT "+KEY_NUMBER+" from "+TABLE + " where " + TYPE + " != '" + <value> + "'", null);`

When this query works fine, then add the ordering clause: `order by key_number`. It should work (at least it works in a MySQL database).

You can see the select syntax for sqlite databases in [this link](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html).

I hope this can solve your problem.